# Swagger/OpenAPI to a human readable document (Excel, Word ...) conversion

Tags: excel, swagger, export-to-csv

is there some tool to generate rest API specification in a MS Excel/MS Word format or any other human friendly table-like document from Swagger/OpenAPI spec in YAML. The result should be accessible to BA and web dev with minimum corrections. I have no particular suggestions regarding columns and structure, the more readable the better.

Preferably script in python or js, but Win10 tool and online are ok. If you suggest a generic YAML or Json CSV/HTML table converter, please indicate why do you think it is great for this task.

Update. Online Swagger Editor actually did decent job and I can copy the result to OpenOffice Writer, then manually edit for best appearance. In Calc the documentation looks bleaker, yet I still hope the docs could look crisper and more appealing with a table processor.

Comment: Did you consider using Swagger UI to render the API spec? Check out the demo at http://petstore.swagger.io.

Comment: Thanks, looks better

Comment: Does anyone know if online swagger sends the API info to the cloud (that would not be cool for confidential projects)? Their https://swagger.io/terms/ is 404.

Comment: Fuhrmanator, deserves a question IMHO, did you try ask them? I am sure cloud kicks if you use codegenerator, but not sure of rest

Comment: Is it possible to export to excel?

Answer (score 1):

As listed above the Swagger UI has a JSON document behind it. It's possible to call this with requests in Python. Then parse out the elements that your interested in.

Answer (score -3):

This library provides Excel editor for Swagger(OpenAPI)
[JSchemaTool](https://github.com/Vineet7805/JSchemaTool)